# Set specific variables based on local hostname

Tags: powershell, hostname

I have been looking all over, but I can't quite find how to do this. I would like to set a specific variable based on the local hostname of my computer.

For example, if the local computer name is COMPUTER1, set this variable. If the local computer name is COMPUTER2, set this variable. Else write-host "Error" and exit.

I have encrypted password files that only work on the machines they were created on. So I want to use one of the password files based on which machine I am using.

Here is the password variable I want to use, based on the computer I'm working from:

```
$Pass = Get-Content "C:\Creds.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

Comment: Is your logic to pick relevant files based on file name ? There are many ways to do it. But wanted to understand the requirement properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.

```
if(($env:COMPUTERNAME -eq 'COMPUTER1') -or ($env:COMPUTERNAME -eq 'COMPUTER2')) {
    $Pass = Get-Content "C:\Creds.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
} Else {
     Throw "Hostname not valid"
}
```

A simple if/else statement to check your computers environmental name otherwise error and exit

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use Switch case for this :

> ```
> $ComputerName = "$env:computername" # GET COMPUTER NAME
> $filename = $null ; # COMMON VARIABLE FOR FILE NAME
> switch ($ComputerName)
> {
>     "COMPUTER1" { $filename = "C:\xyz.txt" }       # CASE 1
>     "COMPUTER2" { $filename = "D:\xyz.txt" }       # CASE 2
>     "COMPUTER3" { $filename = "C:\pass\xyz.txt" }  # CASE 3  
>     default {"ERROR"}                              # DEFAULT CASE ( ERROR )
> } # END OF SWITCH CASE
>
> $Pass = Get-Content $filename | ConvertTo-SecureString
> ```

Comment: This is perfect! It did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a good use case for a lookup-table/hashtable. [*grin*] something like this ...

```
$CompFileLookup =  @{
    LocalHost = 'c:\temp\LocalHost.Key'
    $env:COMPUTERNAME = "C:\temp\$($env:ComputerName).key"
    '127.0.0.1' = 'c:\temp\127-0-0-1.key'
    }
$ComputerNameList = @(
    'LocalHost'
    'BetterNotBeThere'
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    '10.0.0.1'
    '127.0.0.1'
    )

foreach ($CNL_Item in $ComputerNameList)
    {
    $FileToUse = $CompFileLookup[$CNL_Item]

    if ($FileToUse)
        {
        $FileToUse
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ('No matching computer name found for [ {0} ].' -f $CNL_Item)
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
c:\temp\LocalHost.Key
WARNING: No matching computer name found for [ BetterNotBeThere ].
C:\temp\ZK_01.key
WARNING: No matching computer name found for [ 10.0.0.1 ].
c:\temp\127-0-0-1.key
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm not sure how this would work with my request. I'm only looking to say. Run this code if my computer name is A or run this code if my computer name is B. I'm not doing anything with IP addresses. I'm thinking it would be something like this, though I can't quite get the code to work for it:
$env:COMPUTERNAME
if $env is COMPUTER1 set $variable to C:\file1.txt
if $env is COMPUTER2 set $variable to C:\file2.txt

Comment: @Brady - i only have ONE system ... so i used several variants of my local address plus a few other safe variants for computer names. **_the specific names are strictly for sample data to demo the basic idea of using a lookup table._** [*grin*]